# PHP mail configuration acceptable by all mail servers

Tags: php, email

I'm using email check right after registration. I use local sendmail of ubuntu 13.10 server (which has Postfix). The problem is, I have no way to test it with all mail servers. And I know that there are servers that don't receive email from my server.
In fact servers like gmail, hotmail gets email from server. But servers like mail.ru (I tested, neither junk, nor inbox gets email) don't receive email from my servers. Here is my mail class which works with PHPMailer.

```
<?php

class Mail
{
    private $mail;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        $this->mail->IsSendmail();
        $this->mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $this->mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $this->mail->IsHTML(true);

    }

    public function SendIt($to, $from_mail, $from_name, $subject, $message)
    {
        $this->mail->AddReplyTo($from_mail, $from_name);
        $this->mail->SetFrom($from_mail, $from_name);
        $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
        $this->mail->Body = $message;
        $this->mail->AddAddress($to);
        if ($this->mail->Send())
            return true;
        else {
            Yii::log('Mail error: ' . $this->mail->ErrorInfo, "error", "mail");
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions? Maybe I have to use some headers?

Comment: In PHPMailer set ssl true and make sure your php.ini also has ssl socket enabled. Then test it to see if it works or not.

Comment: @MT-Developer why ssl?

Comment: Just check it. It might be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you simple make use of PHPMAILER class for this and you'll have some rest for yourself.

```
https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/
```

This would be of good help so you don't need to start bothering about editing much codes that will drain your time for other works.

Check the files that came in the examples folder for the SMTP examples and use either SMTP advanced or basic. With SMTP advanced, you'll be able to throw and catch your errors. That helps you know where you have errors until all errors are resolved. See sample code for the SMTP basic codes.

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if      not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                       // 1 = errors and messages
                                       // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";   // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

When you are done testing and want to now stop outputting the SMTP buffer messages,   locate this line that says

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
and replace it with

$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->do_debug = 0;
```